# So I am looking for a good framework for my next web project

Tags: language-agnostic

I don't like django. The forms, the url schemes, the way they assume everyone use models on schemaful db (I prefer to use mongodb because it's so clean and easy).

I am pretty much fluent in all the major languages. I do prefer python because it's very clean but also strict (aka function signatures requires you to pass in only X variables etc).

I want something developed and mature - this means that stuff like authentication, registration etc should all be developed and ready to use.

Any suggestions?

TLDR: Need new web dev framework. Requirement: Nothing. Preference: Mongodb, python.

By the way forgot to mention that I might be looking for employment in the web dev industry. So if you can recommend something that is common among big companies that would also be a bonus. like scala's lift for foursquare (if I am not wrong) and php for facebook.

Comment: You don't need to use Django models at all; there are successful examples of using Mongo with it - http://www.google.com.au/search?q=django+mongo. Pretty much any framework you use will have either a traditional ORM or no model system at all. There is a reason why relational databases are popular; they're generally a pretty good match.

Comment: You are fluent in all major languages, very impressive

Answer (score 0):

[Spring](http://www.springsource.org/about) Framework. (Java)

For authentication you can use [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/faq.html)

Comment: I want something fast to code. So java is probably not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Rails. It works with MongoDB via Mongoid and has many authentication solutions. You'll find Ruby very comfortable if you have Python experience.

Comment: Maybe rails is something I could look into. However, I do hate ruby's syntax and convention (which isn't as clean imo).

Comment: You'll ... what!? (I'm primarily a Python programmer and have tried Ruby briefly and dislike the feel of it.)

Comment: Well, I'm sure we can all agree Ruby is better than Java :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) for Python, and I love it.  I'm using SQLAlchemy for Postgre, but it's super minimalistic, so you can use it with whatever you'd like.  I've also heard really good things about [Pylons](http://pylonshq.com/), but don't have any experience with it myself.

Comment: Flask is pretty new. Is it too new as a matter of fact? How stable is it? How hard is it to obtain help online (like IRC?)

Comment: From what I've seen looking at Flask, it seems pretty decent, but it feels like an underpowered ("lightweight" if you prefer) version of Django - reducing the modularity of projects (e.g. routing with decorators rather than `urls.py`), the power of the ORM, things like that.

Comment: Flask is relatively new and is very lightweight.  Which I personally like, however, the fact of the matter is, it's up to you to assemble the parts yourself.

Comment: You know upon closer investigation I realize using flask IS very similar to django. What is the main difference from the developer's point of view?

Comment: I actually haven't spent much time looking at Django, to be honest.  But from what I've seen Django is going to provide you a lot of things that Flask won't.  The scaffolding/admin interface from Django won't be there, syncdb, etc.  With Flask you are going to spend a lot of time configuring the things Django hides by convention.  For me, that's great, as I wasn't interested in that much abstraction, as I'm still relatively new to server-side programming, and like assembling the pieces myself.

Answer (score 0):

Im a big believer in [grails](http://www.grails.org).  Built on best of breed technologies like Spring and Hibernate, you can fall back to java if you have too.  Takes all the pain out of more traditional Java EE development.  Has all the important functionality as plugins, you have access to Spring Security, JMS, everything you need.  Is very convenient as the back end to a RIA, easily render you models as json, easily handle xml.  Its great.

EDIT -- to address the comment, Grails uses the Groovy language, which is scriptable and has some very groovy features.  And it is easy to learn if you are familiar with java.  Has closures, lots of syntactic sugar.

The scripting part is actually quite invaluable -- you write groovy scripts and import your grails classes to whip up functionality to augment your app (like quick queries into your db)

Comment: Probably not java. Probably a *scripting* language

Comment: grails is based on groovy.  which can be used as a scripting language ;)

Comment: Oh sorry I thought the mention of spring and hibernate = java. My bad. I will definitely look into it.

Comment: @ascacw, no problem.  It does use Spring/Hibernate, and in the end gets compiled to byte code, so familiarity with Java helps.  But Groovy is not Java; you get the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you aren't very keen on using Java, but if you don't mind a different language on the JVM I'd suggest taking a look at [Compojure](http://www.compojure.org/), a web framework for Clojure. It isn't a scripting language but can offer close to the same development speeds once you get used to 'the-lisp-way' of doing things.

I'm unaware of a fully featured MongoDB interface specifically for Clojure, but CongoMongo and Adia (I can't include more than the one link currently so you'll need to google them yourself, sorry!) might have (atleast part of) what you're looking for. If nothing else, you could probably just use an existing Java library to access MongoDB or use a different database. Give Compojure a try though, its definitely productive!

Also on a completely unrelated note, this happens to be my first answer on SO, so please be gentle with the downvotes :)

Answer (score 0):

Pylons. 
It will be very fitting for you